# How to place helptext next to a radio button?

Tags: lightning-web-components, helptext, lightning-radiogroup

This sounds trivial but I can't seem to place the helptext right besides the radio button field, if you check [this](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/G1J8HnHWRDL04tkhVUDV) demo you see there is a big gap.

I tried to use grids and custom padding but nothing seems to work, unlike the lightning-input there is no built-in help text attribute per the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined a flex-box with two column and put the help text on the second one, that's why there's a lot of space between it and the radio buttons. [Docs](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/grid/#About-Grids)

> 1. Add a grid container by adding `slds-grid` to an HTML element
> 2. Add as many `slds-col` elements as you want inside of your grid container
>    Initially, **each column takes an equal percentage of the width available**.

The column that contains the radio buttons could be a flex-box too (`slds-col slds-grid`), then you have to simply put the help text next to the radio button (I left the second column):

```html
<template>
    <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters slds-var-p-vertical_medium">
        <div class="slds-col slds-grid">
                <lightning-radio-group
                    name="radioGroup"
                    label="Radio Group"
                    options={options}
                    value={value}
                    type="radio">
                </lightning-radio-group>
                <lightning-helptext content="test"></lightning-helptext>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col">
            Col 2
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

[Try it here](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/x48eexKYG5to22yalRfg/src/app.html?p=stories)

Comment: Thank you @RubenDG